# How are flutter build phase errors which shows grey screen in release mode handled in production apps?

Tags: flutter

How are the flutter build errors which shows grey screen in release mode handled in a production app?

According to flutter [docs](https://docs.flutter.dev/testing/errors#define-a-custom-error-widget-for-build-phase-errors) you can show your own widget but some time this widget itself throws error like render box overflow and such and also when the error happens in a list view it shows the widget multiple times for the each list view items. So I want to know how does these things are handled in a production app? Thanks.

Comment: find `DebugOverflowIndicatorMixin` mixin, find it's `paintOverflowIndicator` method and `ctrl-click` on it to find where it is called